# In Ranorex, I am able to launch the application but after launching it the studio refuses to recognize elements in the software

Tags: xpath, ranorex

I run the application in Ranorex. The next step is to recognize element present in the xpath:

***/form[@controlname='ShellForm']/element[@controlname='LayoutWorkspace']/?/?/element[@controlname='MainWorkspace']/element[@controlname='9673da41-8368-44f4-abe7-2d782f908dd1']//element[@controlname='RightWorkspace']/?/?/tabpage[@accessiblename='Facilities']***

I dragged and dropped this element from view spy. But it fails to recognize any element in the application.

Comment: please use formatting help for better readability

Answer (score 1):

Ok what i suspect is going on looking at your xpath is one of the elements on that page has dynamic naming.  Specifically this element

```
element[@controlname='9673da41-8368-44f4-abe7-2d782f908dd1']
```

I would guess this control has a dynamic name that is generated at runtime.  The error you are getting is caused by the xpath not being valid.  Actually ranorex wrote a blog about how to handle this situation a while ago located [here.](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/automated-testing-and-dynamic-ids)  My first suggestion would be to modify the xPath directly,(be sure to read the documentation on this first).  The first XPath i would try is this one.

```
/form[@controlname='ShellForm']/element[@controlname='LayoutWorkspace']//element[@controlname='MainWorkspace']//element[@controlname='RightWorkspace']//tabpage[@accessiblename='Facilities']
```

You take a small performance hit by removing items in the path directly and using the search all child elements character ("//"), but it makes your xpath cleaner and in many cases more stable

Also in your spy tool you can paste the xpath in directly, and you will be able to see where in the chain is the unrecognized element that is causing issues for you